# UIButton in TableViewCell VoiceOver Accessibility

Tags: ios, uitableview, uibutton, accessibility, voiceover

SOLVED:

I followed the link in the update and now the UITableViewCell's buttons are working for VoiceOver.

The Situation:

I'm implementing VoiceOver accessibility for an app.
I have a custom UITableViewCell (code below) that can toggle between an expanded and a normal visual (selected vs unselected) by the user clicking the cell. Everything involved with expansion works according to my design.
In the custom UITableViewCell, I have a UILabel and 2 UIButtons.
The UILabel is recognized by the VoiceOver accessibility feature, but the UIButtons are ignored.

The Problem:

I need the VoiceOver Accessibility feature to recognize the UIButtons and read their accessibility labels and/or hints.

The Code:

```
-(id) init{
     ...
    _leftButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    _rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [_leftButton.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:FONT size:12]];
    [_rightButton.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:FONT size:12]];
    [_leftButton addTarget:self action:@selector(clickButtonLeft:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [_rightButton addTarget:self action:@selector(clickButtonRight:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [_leftButton setFrame:CGRectMake(CELL_DETAILS_SIDE_PADDING,
                                 CELL_PADDING + CELL_NORMAL_HEIGHT + CELL_EXPANDED_PADDING - CELL_BUTTON_HEIGHT-7,
                                 70, CELL_BUTTON_HEIGHT)];
    [_leftButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"giftIcon.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [_leftButton setTitle:@"  Gift This" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [_rightButton setFrame:CGRectMake(self.frame.size.width - 140 - CELL_DETAILS_SIDE_PADDING,
                                  CELL_PADDING + CELL_NORMAL_HEIGHT + CELL_EXPANDED_PADDING - CELL_BUTTON_HEIGHT-7,
                                  140, CELL_BUTTON_HEIGHT)];
    [_rightButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"buyPack.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [_rightButton setTitle:@"  Buy For Yourself" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    _description = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(CELL_DETAILS_SIDE_PADDING, CELL_PADDING+CELL_NORMAL_HEIGHT+10,
                                                         self.frame.size.width - 2*CELL_DETAILS_SIDE_PADDING, 50)];
    _description.numberOfLines = 0;
    [_description setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
    [_description setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:FONT size:13]];
    [_description setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [_description setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
}

- (void) expandCell
{
    ...
    [self addSubview:_description];
    [self addSubview:_leftButton];
    [self addSubview:_rightButton];
}
```

UPDATE:

It looks like what is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10642877/setting-an-accessibilitylabel-on-a-uiimageview-contained-in-uitableview-header) is the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This other stack overflow question has the answer. Follow the tutorial in the answers.

[stack overflow answer source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10642877/setting-an-accessibilitylabel-on-a-uiimageview-contained-in-uitableview-header)